# Disable controls google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i put a google maps from snazzy maps into my new website, so fine so good, but if try to diasble the zoom function and the controls, is the map displayed off. how can i display off the controls and the zoom in and out ?` google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

```
        function init() {
            var mapOptions = {
                // Map Zoom
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.55741 , 9.96133), // Hamburg


                // Snazzy Maps.
                styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
            };
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.55741   , 9.96133),
                map: map,
                title: 'Awesom Media!'

            })
            ;
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google Maps API docs, to disable the zoom and controls, just add

```
disableDefaultUI: true,
```

to your mapOptions. You can also enable some controls only by adding them to your mapOptions. To get the full list of controls available, just check here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls